# How to know if dialog was destroyed, closed, dimissed?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

I've an activity which opens a custom dialog, this custom dialog when created starts an asynch task which will load the information that will be shown.

In case user closes the dialog, the activity, the application or anything else before the full load I want the async task to stop loading.

This is how I'm doing it:

Activity:

`new UsernamesListDialog().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), USERNAMES_LIST_DIALOG_TAG);`

```
public class UsernamesListDialog extends AppCompatDialogFragment implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener, View.OnClickListener, LoadFollowersTask.LoadFollowersListener {

  public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  new LoadFollowersTask(this, this.progressBar, this.progressCaption, APIFacade.getInstance().getLocalUser()).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, APIFacade.getInstance());


        return v;
    }


public class LoadFollowersTask extends AsyncTask<APIFacade, Integer, Set<BasicUser>> {
  protected Set<BasicUser> doInBackground(APIFacade... api) {
     while (loaded.size() < totalToLoad && this.listener.isAlive()) {
//load stuff      
}

return result;
```

`this.listener` is the own dialog and the method `isAlive()` is:

```
public boolean isAlive(){
return this.isVisible();
}
```

The problem is:

As the tasks are async the `LoadFollowersTask` might get to the while BEFORE the dialog is properly shown into the interface, in this scenario the task will stop itself and return an empty result.

So I need to redefine the `isAlive` to something that will return true from the moment the dialog is created until its get closed

Which method shall I use?

Comment: You can define a variable in your activity on which dialog appears, that changes its value whenever onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) and onPause is called. Then you can check for that value to close your async task.
So let that variable be isDialogOpen and set its default value to false. Stop your async task whenever isDialogOpen is false.

In onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus), hasFocus value that is passed is false when a dialog appears or a recent app button is pressed.When app is killed or destroyed then onPause will be called.

Answer (score 1):

You should try working with Dialog methods `setOnShowListener` and `setOnDismissListener`.
You can get Dialog object when calling `getDialog()` inside `onViewCreated` of your class UsernamesListDialog.

OnShowListener is called when Dialog is shown, so you can run AsyncTask in there.
OnDismissListener is called, when Dialog is closed, so you can cancel any unfinished AsyncTask.